# Spectral radius of perturbed bipartite graphs

Tags: perturbation-theory, spectral-graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, adjacency-matrix, spectral-radius

I am interested in how perturbing a bipartite graph affects its spectrum (specifically its spectral radius or largest eigenvalue). Actually, I am not exactly looking into bipartite graphs but the simplest case can be reduced to a bipartite representation explained below.

Say I have two sets of nodes ${U,V}$. Let $0_{n}$ be an $n \times n$-zero matrix and $B_n$ be a symmetric $(0,1)$-matrix denoting the links interconnecting the two sets of nodes in $U$ and $V$, then I represent the graph via the following $2n \times 2n$ symmetric adjacency matrix

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0_{n} & B_n\\ B_n^{T} & 0_{n}\end{pmatrix}$$

If $B$ is to be perturbed — say, removal or addition of a link — how will the spectrum of $A$ change?

I believe such problem should have been investigated before. Hence, I would appreciate pointers to resources to any previous work looking into such problem. Any bounds or properties would be helpful. My preliminary search points to perturbation theory, which I'm not familiar with. So, even some more elementary resources would be appreciated as well.

So far, I have found a couple of papers that estimate the change of spectral radius for general matrices:

- J. G. Restrepo, E. Ott, and B. R. Hunt, Phys. Rev. Lett. 97, 094102 (2006)
- A. Milanese, J. Sun, and T. Nishikawa, Phys. Rev. E 81, 046112, (2010)

I wonder if there's other results / works such as above which is specific to the perturbations of bipartite graph matrix that I'm studying here.

Also appreciated is pointers to extension of similar problem to $m$-partite graphs.